# Android malformed URL error trying to implement Azure Mobile Service

Tags: java, android, azure, android-studio

I'm trying to implement an Azure Mobile Service in an Android app, using the documentation from inside the Azure portal (Portal > Mobile Service > Android > Connect Existing Android App), and am running into the java malformed URL error when trying to instantiate a `MobileServiceClient`.

Code that is throwing the error:

```
mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
    "https://myurl.azure-mobile.net/",
    "my_secret_squirrel_key",
    this
);
```

The compiler is throwing this error:

> Unhandled exception:java.net.MalformedURLException

I've added the buildscript and compile declarations in the project/app Gradle files. Using version 2.0.3 of the SDK (tried using 2.0.2 as well).

I've added permissions to the manifest file, too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The activity I'm using this in is importing the mobile services library:

```
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.*;
```

And I'm declaring a private member in that same activity to hold the MobileServiceClient like so:

```
private MobileServiceClient mClient;
```

Using Android Studio 1.3.2.

Comment: Trying to use the same implementation as in this tutorial app (line 60) from here (not my code) - https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/blob/master/GettingStartedWithData/AndroidStudio/GetStartedWithData/app/src/main/java/com/example/GetStartedWithData/ToDoActivity.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String)) has a checked `MalformedUrlException`

You need to either add `throws MalformedUrlException` to your calling method, or wrap it in a try/catch:

```
try
{
    mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
        "https://myurl.azure-mobile.net/",
        "my_secret_squirrel_key",
        this);
}
catch(MalformedUrlException ex)
{
    Log.e("Service URL was malformed!", ex);
}
```